# How to present a viewcontroller in UIAlertController?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uiactionsheet

I am struggling with new control **UIAlertController** which replaced **UIActionsheet** and **UIAlertview** in iOS8. In previous versions of iOS, I showed a UIViewController which has tableview and list of items to select in UIActionSheet which doesn't work in iOS8. I could just see **addAction** method which has UIAlertAction. Is there a way I can add a UIViewController to a UIAlertController?

Comment: If your list item is not a big list why don't you manually add one by one , because I'm not finding any ways to add ViewController to UIAlertController try like, `[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"your action title", @"") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                // handle what selection must do
            }]];` You can add any number of titles

Comment: You ask a lot of questions.. but if you don't accept answers. No one will want to help

Comment: @codelgnitor - Yeah, even I didnt find any. I am just animating UIView with tableview in the place of actionsheet when device has iOS 8.0